# Rare bug with ui-grid

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ui-grid

I'm implementing this ui-grid in my project, but its not rendering anything until a resize window event happens, then only the column names are visible, but not the data

[image: Data not renderizes]

> HTML

```
<div ui-grid="shipment.shipmentObject.EventsGridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

> This is the angular controller

```
vm.shipmentObject.events=[];
vm.shipmentObject.commodities=[];
vm.shipmentObject.CommoditiesGridOptions=[];
vm.shipmentObject.EventsGridOptions=[];

    ShipmentResource.getShipment(vm.selectedShipment).then(function(resp)
                {

                    console.log('resp.data', resp.data);
                    console.log('resp.data', resp.data.shipmentExternalId);

                    vm.shipmentObject = resp.data;
                    console.log(vm.shipmentObject);



ShipmentResource.getEvents(vm.selectedShipment).then(function(response){
                            vm.events=response.data;
                            console.log(response);
                            console.log("events",vm.shipmentObject.events);
                            console.log(vm.events);

            vm.shipmentObject.EventsGridOptions = { 
            enableSorting: true,
            data:vm.events,
            columnDefs: [


{field:'shipment_id', displayName:'Shipment ID'},
        {field:'people_id', displayName:'People ID'},
        {field:'date', displayName:'Date'},
        {field:'last_status', displayName:'Last Status'},
        {field:'current_status', displayName:'Current Status'}
                                ]
                        };
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring the grid before you make any requests, then set the data when you have it (as opposed to not configuring it at all until you have data).

I'm assuming you are getting console errors to the effect of *cannot read property of undefined...* That is because the grid cannot get itself configured.

If you want to hide the grid, use `ng-show="shipment.shipmentObject.EventsGridOptions.length > 0"`

```
vm.shipmentObject.EventsGridOptions = {
        enableSorting: true,
        data: [],
        columnDefs: [ // abbreviated. all of your defs here ]
};

ShipmentResource.getShipment(vm.selectedShipment)
  .then(function(resp) {

      vm.shipmentObject = resp.data;

      ShipmentResource.getEvents(vm.selectedShipment)
      .then(function(response) {
          vm.events = response.data;
          vm.shipmentObject.EventsGridOptions.data = vm.events;
      });
```

I would remove these as well. **gridOptions is an object {}, not an array[]**. Both of these grids should be initialized, at the very least with a data property.

```
vm.shipmentObject.CommoditiesGridOptions=[];
vm.shipmentObject.EventsGridOptions=[];
```

This is how they should be initialized:

```
vm.shipmentObject.CommoditiesGridOptions= {
      data: [];
}

vm.shipmentObject.EventsGridOptions= {
      data: [];
}
```

Comment: Just like that?  vm.shipmentObject.EventsGridOptions = vm.events;
or like this  vm.shipmentObject.EventsGridOptions.data = vm.events;... i already try both and its not working :( @Brian

Comment: The latter with .data. What is your console output? You moved the grid options outside of the getShipment() method?

Comment: I added some new comments as well, you have lines where you set gridOptions as arrays, which is incorrect. I covered that now.

Comment: You'll have to provide a demo for people to help. I know you posted a very similar question before, but there is just not enough code to evaluate this correctly. A simple grid works, provided that upon load has a proper gridOptions object available (object with data property).

Comment: Yeah im getting all kinds of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'columnDefs' of undefined" those warning are from the grid from commodities, but the grid for commodities its working,  This is weird, I already did what you suggest but its not showing any data. Actually i have it like this [plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/oTJBxM/) @Brian

Comment: Post all of your controller here. From the angular.module('module',[].controller(.... to the last }. Something isn't being followed here. That tells me that the HTML is loading, it is looking for gridOptions, and there is nothing in it.

Comment: This is more complete plunkr, [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/FzDXDLh624GpRtelX3HE/) thanks btw! @Brian

Comment: You need to have `vm.shipmentObject.CommoditiesGridOptions = {}`... In the root. You have it wrapped in a giant `if()` statement.

Comment: Its now in the root like you suggests... but its not showing data :( i have it lilke this [bloody grid](https://embed.plnkr.co/hIQXxA/) @Brian

Comment: Hey @Brian I found the solution i have to put it like, [this](https://embed.plnkr.co/qnTKqE/) but i dont know how this is working... can you explain me?